# Plotting a function with a indicator part in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have to plot this function:

[image: Desired formula]

I don't even know how to start, it is worth mentioning that I am new to using R, so I have zero knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In indicator part, is there `x`? Like `I(a,b](x)`

Comment: oh right, I forgot that. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function as `func`

```
func <- function(n,x){
  k <- seq(1:2^n)
  tt <- 2^n *(exp((k+1)/2^n) - exp(k/2^n)) * I(k/2^n < x & x <= (k+1)/2^n)
  return(sum(tt))
}
```

and I think support of that `func` is in `(0,1)` so

```
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.001)
fx <- sapply(x, function(t) func(3,t))
plot(x, fx)
```

[image: func]